# ERROR message. Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, real-time-multiplayer

Help me. I am attempting to build a multiplayer game in in unity using photon cloud. i am using the free asset store extension to connect to the server. however, no matter what i do, this error shows:

```
Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

I neither understand what it means nor know what to do about it. can someone help me, please?

my code is this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadServer : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    
    private void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    
    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
    }

    public override void OnJoinedLobby();
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Lobby");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is all of your code? That is a compiler error indicating that you have text after the point where the compiler expects either an end of file or a new type. This usually happens when you have an extra curly brace, typically because you aren't using an editor with good syntax highlighting.

Comment: Get rid of all the semi colons at the end of your method declarations

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon after `OnJoinedLobby()` which is not valid C# syntax.

As a point of advice, use an editor with syntax highlighting like VS Code or Visual Studio. It will detect issues like this for you

Comment: ooooo i didn't notice. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe get rid of the semicolon on public override void OnJoinedLobby();

thanks! @DeveNuub

Comment: thx! didn't see at first.

Comment: hey man for sure!